How to add data to WordPress database from a plugin? may need to pass data from js to php first
I have a boilerplate plugin I used to build a form for a client. Now he would like to collect that data. I can just create a SQL table from phpmyadmin. what I'm thinking is in my index.php config file for the plugin call wpdb insert then pass the data stored in a js array. The JS is fine.
is there any more configuration needed say in functions.php in root? or can i just insert data?
Is this approach going to work? if not why?
How to take a JS variable and pass it as an argument into a php function?
index.php inside my plugin
$data-from-js-array(   
'column1' => $value1 or 'string',
'column2' => $value2 or "string'
)


<? php $wpdb->insert('my-table',
    array(
        $data-from-js-array
    )

here is the boiler plate php file i'm planning to add to. there is some unused functions but it works without errors.
<?php


if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

class BradsBoilerplate {
  function __construct() {
    add_action('init', array($this, 'onInit'));
  }

  function onInit() {
    wp_register_script('makeUpANameHereScript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'build/index.js', array('wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor'));
    wp_register_style('makeUpANameHereStyle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'build/index.css');
    
    register_block_type('makeupnamespace/make-up-block-name', array(
      'render_callback' => array($this, 'renderCallback'),
      'editor_script' => 'makeUpANameHereScript',
      'editor_style' => 'makeUpANameHereStyle'
    ));
  }

  function renderCallback($attributes) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
      wp_enqueue_script('boilerplateFrontendScript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'build/frontend.js', array('wp-element'));
      wp_enqueue_style('boilerplateFrontendStyles', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'build/frontend.css');
    }

    ob_start(); ?>
    <div class="boilerplate-update-me"><pre style="display: none;"><?php echo wp_json_encode($attributes) ?></pre></div>
    <?php return ob_get_clean();
    
  }

  function renderCallbackBasic($attributes) {
    return '<div class="boilerplate-frontend">Hello, the sky is ' . $attributes['skyColor'] . ' and the grass is ' . $attributes['grassColor'] . '.</div>';
  }
}

$bradsBoilerplate = new BradsBoilerplate();


A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

If you have a one-off for a client you might be able to manually create the table, however for testing and growth purposes it might be better to follow best practices for doing this in code.
